# how to select a radio button by clicking on an option and not the actual button itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

say i have the following three options and each with a radio button beside

- London
- Newyork
- Dubai

I need jQuery that when the user clicks on the word the radio button selects!

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in feature in HTML, so no need for JavaScript. Simply use the `label` tag like this:

```
<label><input type="radio"> London</label>
<label><input type="radio"> New York</label>
<label><input type="radio"> Dubai</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. `<label for="london"><input type="radio" id="london"> London</label>`.

Use `label`'s `for` attribute similar to `radio`'s `id`.

1. `<label><input type="radio" > London</label>`

Place the `radio` within `label`.

Very basic `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the label tag:

```
<input id="emptyacct" type="radio" name="account" value="radiobutton" />
<label for="emptyacct">Yes </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just HTML ;)

```
<input id="input_london" type="radio" name="london" value="radiobutton" />
<label for="input_london">London</label>

<input id="input_ny" type="radio" name="ny" value="radiobutton" />
<label for="input_ny">New York</label>

...
```